# No logro mostrar los datos de mis tablas relacionadas

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

tengo unas tablas relacionadas, el problema es que no puedo mostrar de forma correcta los datos. La idea es la siguiente: la tabla *productos* contiene *marca=1* (`1=id del nombre`) y la relacioné con la tabla *marca* en donde el `id=1` es igual a *X* nombre, pero al ejecutar el código me sale un error (comentaré en el código la línea que me marca error) Supongo que tengo bien el código ¿Es probable que sea un problema de caché? Si alguien sabe otra forma de hacer la consulta que empleo en el código

```
$query=" SELECT
            p.id,
            p.descri,
            p.precio,
            m.nombre_m.....(está completo en "código")
```

le agradecería el comentario.

Código.

```
<?php

$conexion = new mysqli("localhost","root","","minos");

$tabla="";
$query="SELECT * FROM productos ORDER BY id";

if(isset($_POST['alumnos']))
{
    $q=$conexion->real_escape_string($_POST['alumnos']);
    $query=" SELECT
            p.id,
            p.descri,
            p.precio,
            m.nombre_m,
            c.nombre_c,
            p.pais,
            p.imagen
        FROM productos p
        INNER JOIN marcas m     ON p.marca  = m.id
        INNER JOIN categorias c ON p.catego = c.id
        WHERE   p.marca LIKE '%".$q."%'
                OR p.catego LIKE '%".$q."%'
                OR p.pais LIKE '%".$q."%'
        ";
}

$buscarAlumnos=$conexion->query($query);
if ($buscarAlumnos->num_rows > 0)
{
    $tabla.=
    '<table class="table">
        <tr class="bg-primary">
                               <td>id</td>
                           <td>descri</td>
                           <td>precio</td>
                           <td>marca</td>
                           <td>catego</td>
                           <td>pais</td>
                           <td>imagen</td>
        </tr>';




    while($filaAlumnos= $buscarAlumnos->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $tabla.=
        '<tr>
            <td>'.$filaAlumnos['id'].'</td>
            <td>'.utf8_encode($filaAlumnos['descri']).'</td>
            <td>'.$filaAlumnos['precio'].'</td>
            <td>'.$filaAlumnos['nombre_m'].'</td> (EN ESTA LÍNEA)
            <td>'.$filaAlumnos['nombre_c'].'</td> (EN ESTA LÍNEA)
            <td>'.$filaAlumnos['pais'].'</td>
            <td>'.$filaAlumnos['imagen'].'</td>
         </tr>
        ';
    }

    $tabla.='</table>';
} else
    {
        $tabla="No se encontraron coincidencias con sus criterios de búsqueda.";
    }


echo $tabla;
?>
```

Ajax.js

```
$(obtener_registros());

function obtener_registros(alumnos)
{
    $.ajax({
        url : 'buscando.php',
        type : 'POST',
        dataType : 'html',
        data : { alumnos: alumnos },
        })

    .done(function(resultado){
        $("#tabla_resultado").html(resultado);
    })
}

$(document).on('keyup', '#busqueda', function()
{
    var valorBusqueda=$(this).val();
    if (valorBusqueda!="")
    {
        obtener_registros(valorBusqueda);
    }
    else
        {
            obtener_registros();
        }
});
```

Comment: Que error te sale?

Comment: Es como que no tomara en cuenta la consulta  $query en donde especifico que debe cambiar el id por el nombre, entonces  en las líneas que marqué salta error de "Undefined index: nombre_m " "Undefined index: nombre_c "

Comment: ¿El valor de `$q` de dónde lo sacas?

Comment: Ya agregué más información para que se puede resolver el problema.

Comment: tienes una imagen de las tablas porfa, para verle todos los campos, ya sea un Modelo E-R o screenshot de la estructura en phpmyadmin, o lo que uses porfa

Comment: Ya lo solucioné, gracias igual por la intención